# Tap on 2 positions at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently working on an app where you can play multiplayer split screen with a friend. You need to tap the buttons to collect falling shapes, but i just found out that when player 1 and player 2 press on the screen at the same time, the tap events just don't work / do anything.

When they don't tap at the same time, the events work perfectly. I couldn't find anything about it on Google.

**This is the code for the taps on the buttons in the screenshot below.**

```
private void Left(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Player.Margin = new Thickness(14, 660, 0, 0);
    PlayerShadow.Margin = new Thickness(16, 660, 0, 0);

}

private void Middle(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Player.Margin = new Thickness(135, 660, 0, 0);
    PlayerShadow.Margin = new Thickness(137, 660, 0, 0);

}

private void Right(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Player2.Margin = new Thickness(256, 660, 0, 0);
    PlayerShadow2.Margin = new Thickness(258, 660, 0, 0);

}

private void Right2(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Player2.Margin = new Thickness(377, 660, 0, 0);
    PlayerShadow2.Margin = new Thickness(379, 660, 0, 0);

}
```

**This is a screenshot of my app while debugging, just to give you an example of what i mean.**

[image: Screenshot of app while debugging]

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders A normal human being would like to get a 'thank you' for any help, removing it makes no sence because there is enough space left and it's only at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Please read the link I posted. You'll find it's not just _my_ opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Hook to the `Touch.FrameReported` event.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported; 
}

void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    TouchPointCollection points = e.GetTouchPoints(this);

    // TODO: do whatever you want with the points
}
```